# Cascaded RF amplifiers - "wiggliness" and flatness

Tags: amplifier, rf, mixer, cascade

I'm designing an application that requires distribution of an LO to a large number of mixers from a single source. The frequency range is 15-18G (3G BW) and the input power level is -5 to +5 dBm (10dB range).

The mixers I am using are well-matched when the LO power is between -6 and +6dBm (12 dB range).  I can go a little above and below, but I'm trying to keep it tight. This means I only really have a tolerance of ±1dB of gain from the source to the input of the 48 mixers.

To do the distribution, I split 12 ways, take these into a backplane, then have 12 modules each split 4 ways.  Plus I have to have bandpass filters, limiters, matching pads, and other lossy elements along the way.

The bottom line is that I have close to 60dB of total losses when you add everything up.  About 1/3 of that is just transmission line losses, the remaining is splitter loss.  I can fairly easily get the gain I need, but the trouble is acheiving a flat response. This is S21 right after the first 1:16 split:

[image]

I've got a nice little suck-out at 16G which gives me about 4dB of delta in power going to the LO of the mixer.

Are there any strategies for "unwigglifying" long RF amplifier cascades?  I mean this is not a simple issue of match or reflection - my insertion loss at various points along the chain is better than 15dB.  Just not sure what the approach should be, and I don't think I can do a whole lot better in component selection.

The first 1:16 power divider has some contribution to this wiggliness, but is significantly flatter overall, and could be equalized out (it's about 1.5dB):

This is what S21 from all paths looks like on the Wilkinson:
[image]

And here's the output VSWR:
[image]

Comment: That "wiggliness" is almost characteristic of what I've seen if you've got a Wilkinson power divider that has an unmatched leg(s). Have you confirmed your dividers are matched? All legs of dividers provide identical responses?

Comment: Jason, great feedback. Our Wilkinson ain't perfect either - but the amplitude unbalance is fairly good (0.5 dB) - see some plots above.

Comment: Suckouts sometimes can be caused by 1) an unexpected resonance somewhere along the path, and 2) a leakage or isolation problem.  I would look closely at your layout and routing, missing ground vias, that sort of stuff.

Comment: @cplusruss those plots do help... however, they look like identical plots? Are my eyes deceiving me?

Comment: Your eyes tell no lies.  I uploaded the same image twice!  Fixed it in the post above.

Comment: @cplusruss This is just a guess... Are all the Wilkinson identical? It could be that they each have a *slight* match problem at 16 GHz. Then when you cascade 4 of them together, it's compounded. Furthermore, it's likely "masked" by the the system loss. So your input match looks "good" but that may because it's going through a lot of loss round trip. I don't feel like it's isolation/coupling/etc as Steve mentioned -- I would expect that to be more pronounced and narrower.